# Scapy: fields to recompute when forging packets

Tags: python, tcp, udp, ip, scapy

I'm forging with Scapy the TTL value in the IP header in some data packet that I captured. Besides the checksum in both IP and transport layer headers, is there anything else I should recompute?

Right now I'm doing:

```
for p in myPackets:
    p[IP].ttl = targetTTL
    del(p[IP].chksum)
    del(p[IP].payload.chksum) 

for i in range(len(myPackets)):
    myPackets[i] = myPackets[i].__class__(str(myPackets[i]))
```

I'm asking this because Scapy's `sr` function, which matches packets with their responses (ICMP in my case) has been returning data with a few RTTs > 1 second, which is absurd since I'm using ttl=1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just sending the packet? Scapy should recompute the checksums for you automatically.You could also try setting them to None, but I don't believe that's necessary.

Comment: It doesn't recompute them. If for instance I don't recompute the IP checksum and I leave an incorrect one, packets will get dropped at the first router.

Comment: @RickyRobinson have you tried setting them to `None` before sending? Have you tried sniffing them to see if they have a `0x0` chksum?

Comment: It definitely does *not* recompute the checksum for you if you're messing with individual fields.  I just lost days because they were being dropped; doing show2() fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe scapy will automatically recalculate the checksums if you call the show2() command on the packet.  So if you have a packet at index 0 in the object pckt, you should call pckt.show2() and the checksum should be correct.  At least that's my understanding.

> pkt.show2()   same as show but on the assembled packet (checksum is calculated, for instance) [Source](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html)

Comment: Yes, in some old post here on stackoverflow I read that show2 does exactly what I wrote in my original post(`myPackets[i] =myPackets[i].__class__(str(myPackets[i])) `), but with no way of suppressing its output on screen.

Comment: @RickyRobinson Ah then what you could do is temporarily change the output of the text.  Use this code to do so: http://pastebin.com/56WjkAg7  Hope that works out for you.

Comment: @RickyRobinson NP and FYI that capture variable will contain the contents of the output if you were looking to parse the text.

Comment: This only shows the chksum to you. The original packet doesn't change. If anyone has another way to calculate the chksum and update the packet, please ping.